# $Push if Object doesn't already exist

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an array of `students` in my Documents `VirtualClass` and my goal is to create a roster with no duplication of students.

I want to match the `VirtualClass` with the teacher and then `$push` the student into an array.

Virtual Class Schema

```
const VirtualClassSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  descriptionHeading: { type: String, required: true },
  room: { type: String },
  teacher: {
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    name: { type: String },
    profile_picture: { type: String }
  },
  students: [
    {
      userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
      name: { type: String },
      profile_picture: { type: String }
    }
  ],
...
```

My current query is as follows

```
      VirtualClass.aggregate([
        { $match: { "teacher.userId": user._id } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            students: { $addToSet: "$students" }
          }
        }
      ])
```

Which returns:

```
[
    {
        "_id": null,
        "students": [
            [
                {
                    "_id": "5e84d1a1ab3ebf54283b8cb2",
                    "userId": "5dd27452592f600900235945",
                    "name": "student  zero",
                    "profile_picture": "https://productionstemulistorage.blob.core.windows.net/stemuli/profile-picture-6e609f3b-44cb-44c0-888a-1b6767e3072d"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "_id": "5e84d1a1ab3ebf54283b8cb4",
                    "userId": "5dd27452592f600900235945",
                    "name": "student  zero",
                    "profile_picture": "https://productionstemulistorage.blob.core.windows.net/stemuli/profile-picture-6e609f3b-44cb-44c0-888a-1b6767e3072d"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected results:

```
_id: null,
"students":
[
     {
       "_id": "5e84d1a1ab3ebf54283b8cb4",
        "userId": "5dd27452592f600900235945",
        "name": "student  zero",
        "profile_picture": "https://productionstemulistorage.blob.core.windows.net/stemuli/profile-picture-6e609f3b-44cb-44c0-888a-1b6767e3072d"
    }
]
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to do `$unwind` on `students` prior to `$group`

Comment: This works thanks, I just have to do roster[0] (roster is the return query), to get the students list. Is there a pipeline function I can call to give me that first value?

Comment: Aggregation always returns an array either it's only one doc or many it doesn't matter your result will be an array.

Comment: Thank you, for clearing that up for a newb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `$unwind` and then `$project` to remove `_id` before `$group` in your aggregate function.

Code:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "teacher.userId": 1
    }
  },
    {
    "$unwind": "$students"
  },
    {
    "$project": {
      "students._id": 0
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "students": {
        "$addToSet": "$students"
      }
    }
  }

]
```

[Example code and Pipeline Explanation](https://play.db-ai.co/m/XqL83QbYvgABFUpe)

Comment: Downvoted - This is really not necessary to unwind the students before. We can remove the field from array without unwinding.  This has been supported since 3.4 version.  We only need to unwind before group to process them as separate documents for uniqueness.You can take a look at here https://play.db-ai.co/m/XqXILX7kZQABtBlO. The mongo playground has a bug it doesn't escape colon it appears.

Comment: But, the question did not mention >=3.4 version.
@SagarVeeram

Comment: I believe  the assumption when the version is not provided is latest supported version which is 3.6 currently. Also exclusion is only supported feature from 3.4 so your query will not even work in versions lower than 3.4. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#exclude-fields . For any 3.4 version and later unwinding is not needed as I mentioned in first comment.

Comment: The question did not mention <3.4 version either. 
and I suggested to `$unwind` first because it seems more understandable than using it later.

Comment: and I just checked your playground which apparently does not give the correct/ desired output. @SagarVeeram

Comment: All I'm saying there is  no need to $unwind - it appears that is what you are claiming when you say `You need to $unwind and then $project to remove _id`. That is playground bug - already notified the app owner. Please test it locally and it works as expected. Thank you -  I don't think we need back and forth on this. I'm clarifying all the right way to do. I have also added a working example in db ai as well. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212568/discussion-between-nafeo-and-sagar-veeram).

Answer (score 3):

You could use exclusion to remove the id from the document before sending it to $addToSet. Also your student is array so you would need `$unwind`.

Something like

```
VirtualClass.aggregate([
  {$match:{"teacher.userId": user._id}},
  {$project:{"students._id": 0}},
  {$unwind: "$students"},
  {$group:{
      _id: null,
      students: {$addToSet:"$students"}
  }}
])
```

example here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/zULrmihM03z

Output

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "students": [
      {
        "name": "student  zero",
        "profile_picture": "https://productionstemulistorage.blob.core.windows.net/stemuli/profile-picture-6e609f3b-44cb-44c0-888a-1b6767e3072d",
        "userId": "5dd27452592f600900235945"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Another alternative would be to set _id to false so mongoose will not generate any id for student.

Something like

```
 students: [
    {
      userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
      name: { type: String },
      profile_picture: { type: String },
      _id:false
    }
  ],
```

You can then use aggregation query without the exclusion.

```
VirtualClass.aggregate([
  {$match:{"teacher.userId": user._id}},
  {$unwind: "$students"},
  {$group:{
      _id: null,
      students: {$addToSet:"$students"}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Looks like mongodb playground is broken now. The query worked fine yesterday. The aggregate query I have works please test locally.

Comment: I've created a bug report here - https://github.com/feliixx/mongoplayground/issues/13. looks like something wrong with having profile picuture as last field with colon in value. I believe this is what happened when it worked for me - example here - https://mongoplayground.net/p/D5l0HK6tVSZ

Comment: FYI - The  mongo playground issue is now fixed.